# Get XML from Generated wsdl2apex code

Tags: wsdl

There is an `Apex Class` in my project which says it was generated by wsdl2apex. How can I see the xml which generated it?

I want to see the request in xml file as am getting the below error

Web service callout failed: Failed to deserialize value '2017-04-10T-2147483648:-2147483648:-2147483648', due to:Unable to parse dateTime

Comment: Your related questions for reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=2017-04-10T-2147483648%3A-2147483648%3A-2147483648

Comment: You can't. You can however look at the endpoint in the invoke method to understand where it may have came from and go from there. Also, some WSDL will include the URL to the schema in the type_infos of a property instead of a urn

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** directly recover the WSDL file that was used to generate the Apex classes from Apex alone. It isn't stored anywhere in Salesforce.

You may be able to retrieve the WSDL yourself from the configured SOAP endpoint. Many times the same endpoint that provides the web service will also provide the underlying WSDL. Try accessing the endpoint with `?WSDL` appended to the URL. The exact syntax will vary based on what is providing the service.

Comment: I have appended ?wsdl to the endpoint url but its not working

Comment: @SuneelChandrasekhar What is the complete endpoint URL?

Comment: its bit confidential to provide the endpoint URL ,issue is response is showing null and it says unable to deserialize the datetime value ,where can i change the value ,it looks fine in the salesforce object.

Comment: @SuneelChandrasekhar If your company controls the URL then it also controls the corresponding WSDL.

Comment: its working in production and we have 4 sandbox regions ,it is showing error in only one sandbox,wondering why it showing error if it is everything uploaded from production.

Comment: @SuneelChandrasekhar You'll need to gather more information for anyone to be able to help you with this. I'd suggest trying to replicate the same callout with something like SOAP UI so you can see what is coming back from the web service in this scenario.